# Angular ng-init within iterating directives doesn't pick up async/delayed data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to set initial values of select boxes dependent on data from another related collection, but at the time data arrives from the wire directives are already compiled. (Delays in the example are emulated with `$timeout`.) So, here's a picture of what i'm trying to achieve, schema is person (likes) fruit:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeCqB.png

http://jsfiddle.net/majwwht5/

#### HTML:

```html
<div ng-repeat='person in people'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='person.name'>

  <select
    ng-model='choice'
    ng-init='choice = find(fruits, {id: person.likes})'
    ng-options='f.name for f in fruits track by f.id'>
  </select>
</div>


<p>
  <input type='button' value='get data'
    ng-click='getData()'>
</p>
```

#### JS:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])

  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$timeout',
    function($scope, Promise, setTimeout) {
      $scope.find = _.find // lodash or underscore


      function getPeople() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            var people = [
              {id: 1, name: 'Jack', likes: 3},
              {id: 2, name: 'Jane', likes: 5},
              {id: 3, name: 'Phil', likes: 4},
              {id: 4, name: 'Pete', likes: 2},
            ]

            resolve(people)
          }, 1000)
        })
      }


      function getFruits() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            var fruits = [
              {id: 1, name: 'apples'},
              {id: 2, name: 'oranges'},
              {id: 3, name: 'bananas'},
              {id: 4, name: 'kiwis'},
              {id: 5, name: 'mangos'},
              {id: 6, name: 'strawberries'},
            ]

            resolve(fruits)
          }, 2000)
        })
      }


      $scope.getData = function() {
        getPeople()
          .then(function(people) {
            $scope.people = people
          })

        getFruits()
          .then(function(fruits) {
            $scope.fruits = fruits
          })
      }
    }])
```

BTW, if you swap the delays with each other (1000 and 2000), then everything works fine. But i can't rely on the order collections come in.

Comment: you should use `$timeout` that will fire digest cycle for you.

Comment: @PankajParkar: I do use `$timeout`, i just renamed it to `setTimeout` for compatibility reasons. Is it bad practice?

Comment: yes, also $scope.yourKey = ... will update the page with the set value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join directly with your person field:

```
<select
    ng-model='person.likes'
    ng-options='f.id as f.name for f in fruits'>
</select>
```

look in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/majwwht5/1/

A single detail on ng-options: you need to remove the "track by", and need to return f.id, to bind directly on a int field.

Comment: wow, what an elegant solution, thank you so much! i'll dig more into the docs to figure out what kind of sorcery is `f.id as f.name...` :)

Comment: You're welcome. I had a similar case on last week, at my code, and I tryed all things on jsbin. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understood your question right...

You are trying to ADD the async arrived values, to the already present ones... Is that correct?

If that is correct, you need to push the arrived values... you are currently replacing the array which will always delete your present values

Just like this...

```
$scope.getData = function() {
    getPeople()
      .then(function(people) {
        for (person in people) {
            $scope.people.push(person);
        }
      })

    getFruits()
      .then(function(fruits) {
        for (fruit in fruits) {
            $scope.fruits.push(fruit);
        }
      })
}
```

Comment: Is that what you meant? And did this solve your problem?

Comment: no, i'm sorry. `.push` adds elements to a view just fine, but the elements in `<select>` aren't chosen as default values.